# how can i add the Unselected Multiselect to Traineemul in zoho creator using deluge script

Tags: lookup, zoho, zoho-deluge

```
variable = List();
for each  r in input.Trainees_Present
{
variable.add(r.Intern_No);
}
input.Trainees_Absent = variable.tostring();
input.TraineeMul:ui.add(variable);`
```

//In this variables added in TraineeMul is which are selected in Trainees_Present

//I want that the variable to be added in TraineeMul which is not selected in Trainees_Present

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any default option to get unselected values from the choice fields or lookup fields.

I can give this as possible workaround for your usecase.

**Case 1 - Lookup Field**

I guess `input.Trainees_Present` is multi select look up field. So you are storing selected values `r.Intern_No` in list.

You can iterate overall values from backend form.

```
unselectedList = List();
for each trainee in Trainee_Form[<Give Criteria if you have any filter for lookup field>]
{
   if(variable.contains(trainee.Intern_No) == false)
   {
      unselectedList.add(trainee.Intern_No);
   }
}
input.TraineeMul:ui.add(unselectedList);
```

**Case 2 - Choice Field - Solution 1**

We have to store the choice fields in some other functions, we have to append all choices in `OnLoad Script`.

Since we have stored total list in one function, we can get unselected list by removing selected items from total list.

**Case 2 - Choice Field - Solution 2**

Zoho Creator provides as API to fetch form fields. We able to get the choices list from the response.

Link to the Documentation: https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/v2/get-fields.html